# How to view Session Variables in Visual Studio 2008 Debugger?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, variables, debugging, session-state

Usually using Visual Studio's debugger is a breeze. Scanning through Locals quickly shows the values of variables, etc. However, I'm at a loss how to find out the values contained in session state variables? Can anyone give me a hand?
Let's say I put a breakpoint right after:

```
Session["first_name"] = "Rob Roy";
```

How do I view the value contained in `Session["first_name"]` from locals?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's pretty simple to inspect the session during debug.  Just put a breakpoint in your code and just highlight your `Session` code (eg. highlight: `Session["first_name"]`) then right click and select `QuickWatch...`.

This will setup up a watch on your `Session` for the value you had defined.  You can also inspect other `Session` elements by adjusting the `Expression` field in the QuickWatch window and clicking the `Reevaluate` button.

Comment: @davemackey If this helped you and is correct, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thank you soo much, I've been going through those stupid tree menus and getting nowhere!!

Comment: I'm looking for a way to view all the Session values at once. I can see all the keys but not their associated values. Do you know if this is possible or can it only be done one-by-one as per your answer?

Comment: @SteveChambers one by one only. If you have all the keys, there is no reason why you couldn't iterate through them and display the values.

Comment: @Kelsey thanks - a shame it isn't possible to view all key/values at once, especially as the Immediate Window doesn't allow looping. The one-by-one approach is doable but not ideal.

Answer (score 12):

In VS you can just put *'Session["first_name"]'* in the Immediate Window and execute while the code is running. That will return the value that it holds.

If you can't find it go to: View **>** Other Windows **>** Command Window, or press Ctrl+W, A

It will look like this:
[image: Screenshot:]

I know its a bit of a late reply but for anyone else who is interested, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it `HttpContext.Current.Session("...")`, I ask as I haven't used ASP.NET for a long time.

Comment: Hmmm...Wasn't able to find anything like that.

Comment: You would use HttpContext.Current.Session("...") outside a Web Form...like in another class.. or DLL.