# How can I see session table in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

In a ASP.NET Project, is it possible to see all the data in session by visual studio. I mean like the way we can see Variable's values in `locals` or `watch` windows when runtime hits a Breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's pretty simple to inspect the session during debug. Just put a breakpoint in your code and just >highlight your Session code (eg. highlight: Session["first_name"]) then right click and select >QuickWatch....
>
> This will setup up a watch on your Session for the value you had defined. You can also inspect other >Session elements by adjusting the Expression field in the QuickWatch window and clicking the Reevaluate >button

[How to view Session Variables in Visual Studio 2008 Debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549424/how-to-view-session-variables-in-visual-studio-2008-debugger)

You can also check session data on the client-side

Comment: How does one check session data on the client side?

Comment: Sorry was mixing Cookies and sessions up